# React - How to render a component inside HTMLElement ref?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, innerhtml

Given a `HTMLElement` ref created by `React.useRef()`, is it possible to render a new Component inside of it?

For example:

```
const DemoComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

  useRenderExample(ref);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref}>RENDER_PLACEHOLDER</div>
      <div>Some other elements and components...</div>
    </>
  );
}

function useRenderExample(ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>) {
  const element = ref.corrent;
  if (element) {
    // 1. This will work:
    element.innerHTML = 'Hello World';

    // 2. This will NOT work (innerHTML except string only):
    // h1 is just an example, I would like to have here
    // a more complex FunctionComponent
    element.innerHTML = <h1>HELLO</h1>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found the **ReactDOM** package - that you are probably already using for rendering your entire application (unless you are using different render engine like ReactNative, ReactVR, etc...).

The ReactDOM come with a few render methods, the one I found useful is `ReactDOM.render(componentToRender, containerElement);`

To solve my issue I used:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function useRenderExample(ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>) {
  const container = ref.corrent;
  if (container) {
    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, container);
  }
}
```

You should also look at `ReactDOM.createPortal(..)` (thank to **Ori Drori** for his answer) that has a similar API parameters. Allows you to render in a different part of the DOM, recommended for popups and tooltips.
(However in my case, no matter how much I tried - I could not make it work)

*As a side node - the HTMLElement could be any element reference, and not only one created with `useRef`. You can also use `document.getElementById` (or other element selector method) or create a new element with `document.createElement` or with `React.createElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [portal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) to render a React element inside a DOM node:

> createPortal lets you render some children into a different part of
> the DOM.

**Example**:

```
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

function useRenderExample(ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>) {
  const element = ref.current;
  
  return element
    ? createPortal(<h1>HELLO</h1>, element)
    : null
}
```

Comment: I'm still on React 16 :-(

Comment: Portals are supported in React 16. How do you use hooks (like `useRef`) in React 16?

Comment: I found it now! I needed to do `ReactDOM.createPortal(...)` and not `React.createPortal(...)`

Comment: That's what this [article](https://handsontable.com/blog/guide-to-react-portals-what-are-they#:~:text=React%20portals%20were%20introduced%20in,attribute%20handling%20and%20error%20boundaries.) says.  However, it's actually based on the [react-portal](https://www.npmjs.com/package//react-portal) package.

Comment: And again - how is this `React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null)` working for you in React 16?!